# Get Index (home) page products using shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

Currently, I am working on a Shopify app and I need to retrieve all products (featured collections) that are shown on the home page.

I tried `{{product}}`, `{{collection.products}}`

I have checked the Shopify [cheat sheet](https://cheat.markdunkley.com/) but I can't find anything useful.
I can access products on the collection page and the home page using Shopify liquid.
Now I want to access products on the index page using Shopify liquid.

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: You are referring to a Shopify App, which means that you are using a code outside the Shopify environment, what does liquid have to do with your App in this case? You are using the wrong terms here (a.k.a you are working on Shopify theme and not App) or you are trying to get products from the front-end in the back-end which is... not OK, you have REST API/GraphQL for this. Please clarify what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: Are you working on an app using the API, or are you building a theme using liquid? It sounds like you are building a theme using liquid, but are referring to it as an app?

Comment: I am working on an app and in my app, I need the index page product's data for some calculation in my app, I am adding `.liquid` files in the user's theme to get data of collections and products using my app, I am getting data perfectly for collections page and products page but I can't find any way to get products/collections data on homepage/

Comment: You cannot get a list of collections displayed on the homepage. Those are likely dynamic section blocks, and that data is scoped to those sections. There is no global liquid object for these settings.

Comment: @kenput3r Thank you for sharing this useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above problem

I have used jquery to find the product handles using script tags, After finding the handle of all products that are displayed on the index (home) page.

I run the following ajax to get product details using product handle.

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: "/products/product-handle.js",
   dataType: 'json',
   async: false,
   success: function(p) {
     //after function success the data of every product is stored in p variable
   }
})
```

Now I am able to do other calculations with product data.